Multiplication in Hecke algebra for $\mathrm{GL}_2$
Let $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(F)$ for a $p$-adic field $F$, and let $K = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathcal O_F)$ for the ring of integers $\mathcal O_F$ of $F$. I want to make the multiplication in the Hecke algebra $\mathcal H(G/\!/K)$ explicit by using the formula convolution stated in this question of mine.
For this, pick the right Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$ to be normed with $\mu(K) = 1$. Note that $G$ is unimodular.
For example, we have
$$K \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ & \pi\end{pmatrix} K = K \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ & \pi\end{pmatrix} \amalg \coprod_{\bar x \in k_F} K \begin{pmatrix}\pi & x \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\pi$ is the uniformiser and where $k_F$ is the residue field. Using the formula, we have
$$1_{K \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ & \pi\end{pmatrix} K} * 1_K = \mu(K) 1_{K \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ & \pi\end{pmatrix} K} + \sum_{\bar x \in k_F} \mu(K) 1_{K \begin{pmatrix}\pi & x \\ & 1\end{pmatrix} K} = (q+1) 1_{K \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ & \pi\end{pmatrix} K}$$
where $q = \# k_F$.
What did I get wrong? $1_K$ should clearly be the identity in $\mathcal H(G/\!/K)$, not multiplication with $q+1$. Simply defining $\mu(K) = (q+1)^{-1}$ wouldn't work as well since then, $1_K * 1_K = (q+1)^{-1} 1_K$.
